# Não consigo exibir todos os dados com foreach no PHP com dados de um API

Tags: php, json, api, foreach

Estou tentando trazer para um modo mais simples a seguinte informação vinda de uma API:

```
{
"results": [
    {
      "date": "2020-01-05T00:00:00Z",
      "total": 100,
      "visits_detail": [
      ]
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-01-06T00:00:00Z",
      "total": 200,
      "visits_detail": [
      ]
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-01-07T00:00:00Z",
      "total": 300,
      "visits_detail": [
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

O que desejo fazer é transformar essa parte do código em algo parecido com isso, transformando a data do Padrão ISO8601 para Datetime, assim, não terei problemas em exibir os dados com Apexchart.

```
{
"results": [
    {
      "date": "05-01-2020",
      "total": 100,
      "visits_detail": [
      ]
    },
    {
      "date": "06-01-2020"",
      "total": 200,
      "visits_detail": [
      ]
    },
    {
      "date": "07-01-2020"",
      "total": 300,
      "visits_detail": [
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Acontece que enrosquei e não consigo fazer com que todas as informações sejam acessadas dentro do foreach. Esse é meu código:

```
foreach ($myArray2['results'] as $key => $value)
{
  $data1 = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($myArray2['results'][$key]['date']));
  $data2 = $myArray2['results'][$key]['total']; 
}
$arrayfinal = array('results'=> (array('date'=>$data1,'total'=>$data2)));
echo json_encode($arrayfinal);
```

E a resposta que recebo é somente essa, não consigo exibir todos os itens, além de não estar em formato de array.

```
{
"results": {
"date": "07-01-2020",
"total": 300
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note que dentro do foreach, existe duas variavéis $data1 e $data2, elas irão armazenar a ultima informação que foi iterada no laço, pois é uma simples variável.

Se você deseja alterar a data diretamente no array é possivel, segue um exemplo.

```
<?php 
$myArray2= [];

$myArray2["results"][0]["date"] =  "2020-01-05T00:00:00Z";
$myArray2["results"][1]["date"] =  "2020-01-05T00:00:00Z";
$myArray2["results"][2]["date"] =  "2020-01-05T00:00:00Z";


var_dump($myArray2);

foreach ($myArray2['results'] as $key => $value) {
    $myArray2['results'][$key] = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($myArray2['results'][$key]['date']));;
}

var_dump($myArray2);
```

O resultado é o mesmo, porém esta tratando a variável diretamente no mesmo array.

```
VAR_DUMP-1 = array(1) { ["results"]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { ["date"]=> string(20) "2020-01-05T00:00:00Z" } [1]=> array(1) { ["date"]=> string(20) "2020-01-05T00:00:00Z" } [2]=> array(1) { ["date"]=> string(20) "2020-01-05T00:00:00Z" } } } 
VAR_DUMP-2 = array(1) { ["results"]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { ["date"]=> string(10) "04-01-2020" } [1]=> array(1) { ["date"]=> string(10) "04-01-2020" } [2]=> array(1) { ["date"]=> string(10) "04-01-2020" } } }
```

Comment: De qual forma eu consigo inserir no mesmo array o Total das visitas em cada data?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver criando um novo array com os resultados:

```
foreach ($myArray2['results'] as $key => $value) {


    $myArray2['results'][$key] = array('date' => date('d-m-Y', strtotime($myArray2['results'][$key]['date'])),'total' =>$myArray2['results'][$key]['total']);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Para modificar diretamente elementos de um array dentro de um laço](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php), preceda `$value` com `&`. Neste caso, o valor será atribuído por [referência](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.references.php).

```
foreach ($myArray2['results'] as $key => &$value){
    $value["date"] = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($value["date"]))
}
unset($value); //Elimina a referência remanescente
```

[Link do exemplo funcional no Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/PeruShockingDatamining)